# array push seems not working here

Tags: php, arrays, function, output, array-push

```
$files = array();

function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';

    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            else echo '<li>'.$ff;

            array_push($files, array('file' => $dir.'/'.$ff, 'hash' => hash_file('md5', $dir.'/'.$ff)));
            echo '</li>';
        } 
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('/var/www');
var_dump($files);
```

Why i'm getting empty output here?

```
array(0) { };
```

Comment: Do you see the "echo"?

Comment: yes.it's working nicely

Comment: your array is declared outside the function

Comment: Aren't you getting warnings about accessing an uninitialized variable? If not, make sure you have error reporting turned up fully.

Comment: @Barmar no i'm not getting any warnings here.All are turn on

Comment: do not use globals, it's bad practice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a scope issue. Your `$files` array variable is outside of your function.

You need to pass that as a parameter as a reference (Tipped by [*@Barmar* ;)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) ) to it..

#### The right way..

```
function listFolderFiles($dir,&$files){
```

and call it like.. `listFolderFiles('/var/www',$files);`

You are passing it as a reference because you are not returning the array , so whatever changes done inside the function to the array will remain there itself. So you need to add reference as shown in the method signature. This will modify the original array itself.

Comment: It needs to be passed by reference.

Comment: This answer worked after adding the reference.Why is that & mean ? @Barmar

Comment: @samitha, I have explained in the answer. Please see.

Comment: @samitha the reference (&) means that it changes the variable after processing the function

Comment: @samitha I'd suggest to read much more the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a variable by reference, as in Shankar's answer. Or you can have the function return a result:

```
$files = listFolderFiles($dir);    

function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $files = array();
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';

    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            else echo '<li>'.$ff;

            array_push($files, array('file' => $dir.'/'.$ff, 'hash' => hash_file('md5', $dir.'/'.$ff)));
            echo '</li>';
        } 
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    return $files;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For you purposes here, it may be better to declare the files variable inside the function itself, and return it at the end. This way, the function will be re-usable:

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $files = array();
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';

    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            else echo '<li>'.$ff;

            array_push($files, array('file' => $dir.'/'.$ff, 'hash' => hash_file('md5', $dir.'/'.$ff)));
            echo '</li>';
        } 
    }
    echo '</ol>';
    return $files;
}

$files = listFolderFiles('/var/www');
var_dump($files);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use globals

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){

global $files; // global var

    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){

        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){

            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            else echo '<li>'.$ff;
            array_push($files, array('file' => $dir.'/'.$ff, 'hash' => hash_file('md5', $dir.'/'.$ff)));
            echo '</li>';

        }
```

Comment: bad idea, do not follow it

Comment: @royal why, i used it jst yestiday to solve a scope issue i had. is there a better way?

Comment: @longJOURNEY See Shankar's answer.

Comment: Although it would work, it is nearly always bad practice to use globals. Why define something to be available everywhere when you just need it at a much smaller scope?

Comment: it resolves the scope issue for the current need, but leaves the code leaning on globals. A well structured app will not lean on globals. Better way is Shankar's answer. And best is to use objects and instance variables which will change i.e. `private $_files = array(); public function listFolderFiles($dir) { array_push($this->_files, array(....)); }`

Comment: @Bowdzone Note that PHP globals aren't available everywhere, only in the functions that have the `global` declaration, and in the non-function code. So they're not as bad as global variables in other languages.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the clarification, I was not aware of that

Comment: @Barmar practice shows that apps that lean on globals has a page that loads on each other (i.e. included in each page), which has these global variables, that are used in functions which had globalized the variables as well. Which, according to me, is fractal of bad design. For better design everything should be encapsulated. And `files` property should be muttable only from its own object, and to refer to this `files` property, you have to refer to its object aswell